# Angular source files visible in browser. How to hide?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

After building my angular js project using npm build command,I am getting .tmp folder with index.ejs file. How to invoke index.ejs file while hitting the URL to hide source files?

I Am using angular 1.x and node 4.x.

Comment: It will be hidden after the production build process.

Comment: Alright! Do we need to write any script to hide the files during prod build??

Answer (score 1):

Build using production build

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Comment: Thank you! But it is not supporting for node v4.5.0

Comment: then you need some task runner like gulp or grunt to minify and uglify your code for production build

Comment: Ok! I can able to minify the code and got a package. Eventhough am not sure how to invoke the minifed files.

Comment: You need to have a look at this thread
https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1255912-protectinghiding-angularjs-codes/